# Bootstrap glyphicons not displaying in Windows 10 in IE11

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, windows-10

My company is getting ready to move to Windows 10 operating system. At the same time, I've been developing a new website to display benefits information using html and jquery and I am using Bootstrap Glyphicons. We have discovered that the bootstrap glyphicons that I'm using on the page do not display in internet explorer 11 on computers that have Windows 10 installed. The glyphicons do display in IE & Chrome on windows 7 computers and do display in Chrome on Windows 10 computers (just not IE, windows 10 combinations).

Perhaps, more interesting, I believe I'm seeing the same issue with the bootstrap site itself: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons When viewing this site on a Windows 10 machine in IE, I do not see most of the glyphicons. The tiles on the page simply contain the glyphicon names without any glyphicon icons. (I see the glyphicons in all other 3 combinations). I have cross-checked the IE settings between Windows 7 and Windows 10 and they all seem to be the same. Furthermore, both Windows 7 and Windows 10 machines are using IE 11. Any ideas of how to make the bootstrap glyphicons appear on our Windows 10 machines in IE 11 ?

Any help very appreciated!

**UPDATE** It's not just bootstrap. If I go to font awesome, or glyphicon website they also do not appear on our windows 10 machines while using IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My manager found the solution to this problem. Turns out in Windows 10, there is a new policy that blocks 'untrusted fonts'. If this is enabled it will block IE from downloading new fonts. We also had issue of this blocking icons from appearing on Office 365. Here is the article explaining the issue and how to resolve it: https://jprudente.wordpress.com/2016/02/02/ie11-on-windows-10-not-displaying-certain-graphics/